# Python : certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate when using SSL wrapper

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, wrapper

In Python, I'm writing a simple FTP server and client that I want to secure with TLS.
For that, I use the TLS/SSL wrapper offered by Python.

My problem is that I always get the following error at the moment the client runs socket.connect :

> Exception has occurred: SSLCertVerificationError [SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)   File
> "/work/Python/hsireportClient/hsireportClient.py", line 167, in
>
> f_socket.connect(f_server)

This is how I start listening on the server side :

```
from socketserver import ThreadingTCPServer
from app.mod_report.controlersTCP import tcpRequestHandler
import ssl

...

sslcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
sslcontext.load_cert_chain('/work/Python/hoaReport/ssl/hoizey_net.crt','/work/Python/hoaReport/ssl/certificat.key')

f_listen = ('0.0.0.0', 6667)            # TODO : Paraméter le port en base de données
f_server=ThreadingTCPServer(f_listen, tcpRequestHandler)
f_server.socket=sslcontext.wrap_socket(f_server.socket, server_side=True)
f_server.serve_forever()
```

and how I connect to the server on the client side :

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY
from ssl import SSLContext, PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT, CERT_REQUIRED
from certifi import where as certifi_where

...

# Creates SSL Context
f_context = SSLContext(PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
f_context.verify_mode=CERT_REQUIRED
f_context.load_verify_locations(cafile=path.relpath(certifi_where()), capath=None, cadata=None)

# Opens the socket and connets to the server
f_socket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
f_socket=f_context.wrap_socket(f_socket, server_hostname=f_serverHost)

f_serverPort=int(f_serverPort)
f_server=(f_serverHost, f_serverPort)

f_socket.setsockopt(IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, 1)
f_socket.setblocking(True)
f_socket.connect(f_server)
```

My server certificate has been signed by Comodo, and I checked the CA root certificate exists in the file certifi.where() points to.

Of course, everything works fine if I remove SSL wrapper.

I searched a lot about this problem, and I noticed it occurs quite frequently, but I couldn't find a solution, and I have to admit I don't understand what goes wrong.

Please, does anybody can help with this ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the content of `hoizey_net.crt` ? It is not sufficient for proper validation that it contains the server certificate. It must instead contain the server certificate and all intermediate certificates which are needed to create the trust chain to the root certificate, in the correct order. If these intermediate certificates are not provided, then the client cannot build the trust chain and the verification and thus the TLS handshake will fail.

Comment: *"... a simple FTP server ... `('0.0.0.0', 6667)` ..."* - port 6667 is traditionally used for [IRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat). It's usually not a good idea to run a completely different kind of service there. FTP like defined in RFC 959 is used on port 21 (explicit FTP) or maybe port 990 (implicit FTP).

Comment: Thank you for your help. hoizey_net.crt actually only contained the certificate. I didn't understood I had to concatenate all intermediate certificates with it. So I did it, and it works much better now. Actually I now get another error (certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'localhost') but this is because I connect to localhost and not to my target server. I'll fix it tomorrow.

Comment: And also, I wrote "_FTP server_" but I wanted to write "_TCP server_". I'm actually transferring file via TCP to my server. Anyway, 6667 is not the final port. I just kept what I found in some examples. But thank you for mentionning it.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Steffen Ullrich, I manage to get my certificates orking as expected.

I just had to add all intermediary certificate in my certificate file and that did the job.

Thanks a lot for your help